# How to group by the first 5 columns from left and summarize the last 2 columns from right by sum each others using rstudio

Tags: rstudio

I have data frame (.csv) and I need to group by the first 5 columns (Date, APN, PLMN, TAC,ECGI) then summarize the the other last 2 columns (DL_Data, UL_Data) by sum each column separately per grouped columns so output table should be 3 rows instead of 4 rows as row1 & row2 have same grouped data (20230125, moe-dyn.te.eg, 60201, 33757) while sum (67 & 67) to be 134 in same column & sum (117 & 117) to be 234 in same column

```
      Date                   APN    PLMN   TAC     ECGI   DL_Data    UL_Data
 1: 20230125               moe-dyn 60201 33757  5681666        67        117
 2: 20230125               moe-dyn 60201 33757  5681666        67        117
 3: 20230125               moe-dyn 60203 62201 11442948   1004116    3317123
 4: 20230125                abe-st 60203 62203 10602499    378612     494496
```

So I'm using rstudio and here is the code >>

```
TAI_data <- read.csv(header=FALSE, file.choose()) 
TAI_data1 <- TAI_data %>% group_by(Date,APN,PLMN,TAC,ECGI) %>% summarise(across(c(DL_Data, UL_Data), sum))
```

Comment: Please try to rephrase the question: it is not easy to follow

Comment: Hi - those details are helpful - please add them back to the body of your question